# CSS: Unable to set tbody height in % for scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying the CSS solution to scrolling table contents while keeping the header fixed.

CSS Code 1:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    *   {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }
    #ListData   {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background:#ffffff;
    }
    #ListData table {
                    width:100%;
                }
    #ListData thead {
                    position:relative;
                    width:100%;
                    height:20px;
                    overflow:auto;
                    background:#0099cc;
                }
    #ListData tbody {
                    position:relative;  
                    width:100%;
                    height:300px;
                    overflow:auto;
                }               
    </style>
```

The  output for this style is here : 
http://riotdesign.in/test.php

This works fine in Firefox (i dont care about IE at the moment.. )

However, if i use percentages instead of px or em:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    *   {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }
    #ListData   {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background:#ffffff;
    }
    #ListData table {
                    width:100%;
                }
    #ListData thead {
                    position:relative;
                    width:100%;
                    height:10%;
                    overflow:auto;
                    background:#0099cc;
                }
    #ListData tbody {
                    position:relative;  
                    width:100%;
                    height:50%;
                    overflow:auto;
                }               
    </style>
```

This is what i get : 
http://riotdesign.in/test2.php

What am i doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 3):

At some point, your objects need to have a `block` level parent element with a definitive size in order to get the scrolling you want.

Specifically in your case, either the containing DIV `ListData` or the `ListData table` need to have specific height.

When adding percentage values for height and width, make sure you know the answer to "x% of what...?" and follow that question up the chain until you hit something with hard boundaries. If you make it to the `Body` element and still do not have a hard boundary, you will not get the effect you desire.

I tested both of these in Firefox 3.5.xx and got the `tbody` to scroll:

```
#ListData
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

or

```
#ListData table {
   width:100%;
   height: 200px;
}
```

This also works:

```
body
{ 
  width: 100%;
  height:600px;
}
```

Comment: what if my body is set to {width:100%; height:100%} ? Because i want my page to be size-able.

Comment: Something has to have a concrete edge. It could be a container div, body or the table itself.

Comment: Otherwise, 'Overflow` is meaningless

Comment: Okay, i tried setting definite dimensions for my body tag. The problem remains.

Comment: Did your dimensions exceed the bounds of your screen? For the scroll bars to appear, your tbody must be restricted to something less than the available area. If everything is a percentage then the available width is your screen width and the available height is infinity. Likewise, if you have a concrete boundary beyond the screen size, then the parent element's scroll bars are sufficent